# Detail template in Django not taking values

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views, django-generic-views

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Inspectionfile
from .models import  posts

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "posts/index.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    return Inspectionfile.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Inspectionfile
    template_name = "posts/detail.html "

#index template
<ul>
  {% for o in object_list %}
    <li><a href = "/posts/{{o.id}}/">{{o.document_title}} </a> </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>


#detail template
 <h1>{{ o.document_title }}</h1>
```

My Index template works but the detail template does not seem to take the value so just appears blank . So is the 'o' not being passed to detail ?? I have not been able to solve this. BTW document_title is one of the field of my inspectionfile model. I checked my url regex and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`o` is an object which only exists within the for loop in your list view template. It isn't passed anywhere.

The detail view has its own context; there the object that is identifued by the url argument is called just `object`.

Comment: That was my first thought!! But then I saw some people doing it this way , they must have global object or something. Anyways worked like a charm!! Thank you so much!!